# MATE - add new custom menu to panel

Tags: mate, menu, panel

I can see how to add a prepackaged menu through the Panel.AddItem feature

and how to add a new subtree to an existing menu through the menu editing function

but I want to add a new root node to the MATE panel.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean MATE Panel or MATE Menus (like *Applications*)? Will `mozo` (MATE Control Center → *Main Menu*) be a solution for your problem?

Comment: @N0rbert mozo adds a submenu to the toplevel menu (like Applications). I want to add a new toplevel menu.